# Unhighlight a Row in a rich:ScrollableDataTable

Tags: java, jsp, jsf, richfaces

In my application I need a user to be able to select a row in a table.  When they are done working with the data from that row they click a cancel/reset button to reset some other page elements.  What I need to do is to also have the reset button unhighlight or unselect the highlighted/selected row in the datatable.  I have been unable to figure out what to do in my backing bean to get this working.

From my JSP page:

```
<rich:scrollableDataTable id="adjusterScheduleScrollableDataTableId" height="200px"
           width="807px" rows="10" sortMode="single" var="item"
           value="#{controller.searchResults}" selectionMode="single"
           binding="#{controller.table}" selection="#{controller.selection}">
      <a:support event="onRowClick" action="#{controller.enableTools}" reRender="tools"/>
      ...
      multiple columns 
      ...
</r:scrollableDataTable>
<h:panelGroup id="tools">
    <h:commandButton id="reset" action="#{controller.reset}" value="Reset" />
</h:panelGroup>
```

From my backing bean:

```
private UIScrollableDataTable table;private Selection selection;
...
    public String reset(){
        //WHAT GOES HERE TO UNSELECT ROW??
    }
...
```

Comment: Please make your question clear..

Comment: I dont know what you mean?  When the table is shown and row is clicked on that row is highlighted.  I want to click reset and from the backingbean unhighlight that row.  Is there anything unclear in that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I managed to figure out the solution to my problem.  Im actually suprise no one was able to answer this.

```
private UIScrollableDataTable table;private Selection selection; 
... 
   public String reset(){ 
       table.setSelection(new SimpleSelection());
   } 
...
```

Comment: You can also use `this.selection.addKey(0);` to select the first row. @SomeFatMan

Answer (score 0):

Two things need to be cleared, the active row and selected row.

```
private UIScrollableDataTable table;
table.setActiveRowKey(-1);
((SimpleSelection)table.getSelection()).clear();
```